# Quicksort - Media of Three chosen pivot

Tags: python, quicksort

```
def quicksort(L, low, high):
    total = 0
    if low < high:
        pivot_location, total = Partition(L, low, high)
        total += quicksort(L,low,pivot_location)
        total += quicksort(L,pivot_location + 1, high)
    return total 

def Partition(L, low, high):
    print(L)
    #print(high)
    total = 0
    if (high - low) % 2 == 0:
        middle = (high - low) // 2 - 1
    else:
        middle = ((high - low) // 2) + low
    print(L[low])
    print(L[high - 1])
    print(L[middle])
    numbers = []
    numbers.append(L[low])
    numbers.append(L[middle])
    numbers.append(L[high - 1])
    if L[low] > L[middle] and L[low] < L[high - 1]:
        pivot = L[low]
    elif L[low] >L[high -1] and L[low] < L[middle]:
        pivot = L[low]
    elif L[middle] < L[low] and L[middle] > L[high -1]:
        temp = L[low]
        L[low] = L[middle]
        L[middle] = temp
        pivot = L[low]
    elif L[middle] < L[high - 1] and L[middle] > L[low]:
        temp = L[low]
        L[low] = L[middle]
        L[middle] = temp
        pivot = L[low]
    elif L[high - 1] < L[low] and L[high - 1] > L[middle]:
        temp = L[low]
        L[low] = L[high - 1]
        L[high - 1] = temp
        pivot = L[low]
    else:
        temp = L[low]
        L[low] = L[high - 1]
        L[high - 1] = temp
        pivot = L[low]
    print(pivot)
    i = low + 1
    for j in range(low + 1,high,1):
        total += 1
        if L[j] < pivot:
            temp = L[j]
            L[j] = L[i]
            L[i] = temp
            i += 1
    temp = L[low]
    L[low] = L[i -1]
    L[i - 1] = temp
    #print(L)
    return i - 1,total  

c = [2148,9058,7742,3153,6324,609,7628,5469,7017,504]
print(quicksort(c, 0, len(c)))  
print(c)
```

I have implemented quicksort this way. I tried using first element as pivot and last element as pivot and it worked perfectly. However I can't figure out how to choose as a pivot the median of the three elements: first, middle, last. Any help on how to choose in each recursive call the middle element. Note that I want to pass as an argument to each recursive call the whole array because I don't want to use any extra memory.

Comment: Yes, I am doing this but the problem is that I can't figure out how to choose the middle item in each subarray of each recursive call. The borders of each subarray in each recursive call are set from the values of low and high variables.

Comment: No, using the code I posted below p, the middle element of race partitioned subarray isn't being selected properly. I need a way to choose the right middle element of each partitioned subarray.

Comment: There is also another bug: Calculation of middle `middle = (high - low) // 2 - 1` should probably have had a `high+low` and no `-1`. In any case: `middle = (low + high) // 2` should be good for both odd and even `high-low`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to put median of 3 elements into position:

```
def compareswap(L,a,b):
    L[a], L[b] = min(L[a],L[b]),max(L[a],L[b])

def medianfirst(L,a,b,c):
    compareswap(L,b,a) # L[b]<=L[a]
    compareswap(L,b,c) # L[b]<=L[c] i.e L[b] smallest
    compareswap(L,a,c) # L[a]<=L[c] i.e L[c] largest
```

Now use `medianfirst` in `Partition` with:

```
    medianfirst(L,low,middle,high-1)
    pivot = L[low]
```

instead of the big `if-elif-else` block.

---- UPDATE ----

(fixed `middle` to choose first in even elements interval)
For convenience, a revised `Partition`:

```
def Partition(L, low, high):
    print(L)
    total = 0
    middle = (low+high-1)//2
    medianfirst(L,low,middle,high-1)
    pivot = L[low]
    i = low + 1
    for j in range(low + 1,high,1):
        total += 1
        if L[j] < pivot:
            L[i],L[j] = L[j],L[i]
            i += 1
    L[low],L[i-1] = L[i-1],L[low]
    return i - 1,total
```

Comment: Well, your suggestion works pretty well. Although if for example I have the following array: [2 0 8 1], I would like to take as middle the number 0 and not the number 8. Could you help me with that maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def partition_median(L, low, high):
    left = L[low]
    right = L[high-1]
    length = high - low
    if length % 2 == 0:
        middle = L[int(low + length/2 - 1)]
    else:
        middle = L[int(low + length/2)]
    pivot = median(left, right, middle)
    pivotindex = L.index(pivot) #works only for unique values
    L[pivotindex] = L[low]
    L[low] = pivot
    i = low + 1
    for j in range(low + 1, high):
        if L[j] < pivot:
            temp = L[j]
            L[j] = L[i]
            L[i] = temp
            i += 1
    leftend = L[low]
    L[low] = L[i-1]
    L[i-1] = leftend
    return i - 1
```

Well, thanks to the help I got and some more thought I managed to implement what I wanted with the above partition subroutine!

Comment: To choose middle and get 0 out of [2 0 8 1], it is enough to do `middle = (low+high-1)//2`. No need for `if`s and `length`s.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also did that and worked properly. Thank you for the help!